# Resetting Row number according to record data change

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I have got the set of data as follow

```
name  date  
x     2014-01-01
x     2014-01-02
y     2014-01-03
x     2014-01-04
```

and I'm trying to get this result

```
name  date           row_num
x     2014-01-01      1
x     2014-01-02      2
y     2014-01-03      1
x     2014-01-04      1
```

I have tried to run this query

```
select name,
    date,
    row_number () over (partition by name order by date) as row_num
from myTBL
```

but unfortunately I get this result

```
name  date           row_num
x     2014-01-01      1
x     2014-01-02      2
y     2014-01-03      1
x     2014-01-04      3
```

Please help.

Comment: which database - sql server, oracle etc. ? what is the logic for assigning the row number this way ? what are you trying to do finally ?

Comment: Your `partition by` statement says that partitions are based solely on `name`. The result you got is the result you asked for.  The result you seem to want is that partitions reset every time a *run* of `name` changes. I don't think you can do this with a simple window function. You'll need one or two levels of subquery.

Comment: For future askers, this falls into the class of problems known as [tag:gaps-and-islands].

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to identify the groups of `names` that occur together.  You can do this with a difference of row numbers.  Then, use the `grp` for partitioning the `row_number()`:

```
select name, date,
       row_number() over (partition by name, grp order by date) as row_num
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by name order by date)
             ) as grp
      from myTBL t
     ) t
```

For your sample data:

```
name  date         1st row_number   2nd      Grp
x     2014-01-01         1           1        0
x     2014-01-02         2           2        0
y     2014-01-03         3           1        2
x     2014-01-04         4           3        1
```

This should give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: This is a very useful solution, because it should work on any database which supports `ROW_NUMBER()` (which is most of them) +1.

Comment: thanks indeed this was helpful in my situation as well

Comment: What an elegant solution. This kind of thing makes math look beautiful.