# SQL Server Increment running total based on other column

Tags: sql-server

Trying to find an efficient way to create the column C values which is based on column B and increments based on B being 1 or -1 and the count restarts when B switches between B being 1 or -1.

```
CREATE TABLE #T (a int, b int, c int);   
INSERT INTO #T VALUES (1, 1, 1), 
(2, 1, 2), 
(3, -1, -1), 
(4, -1, -2), 
(5, -1, -3), 
(6, -1, -4), 
(7, 1, 1), 
(8, 1, 2);
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No :)  Thank goodness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to group column `b`. You can do this with the base code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27681135/1663001). Now you need to switch the incrementer to be positive or negative. Easiest way to do that is to multiply the value by column `b`. For example:

```
SELECT 
   a,b,    
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b, grp ORDER BY a) * b as c
FROM (SELECT T.*,
             (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) -
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b ORDER BY a)
             ) as grp
      FROM T) T
ORDER BY a
```