# Postgresql group by recurring items

Tags: postgresql, group-by, lag, partition-by

I'm using postgresql to store historical data coming from an RTLS platform.
Position data is not collected continuosly.
The historical_movements is implemented as a single table as follow (it is a simplified table but enough to present the use case):

```
User   Area   EnterTime               ExitTime
John   room1  2018-01-01 10:00:00     2018-01-01 10:00:05
Doe    room1  2018-01-01 10:00:00     2018-01-01 10:10:00
John   room1  2018-01-01 10:05:00     2018-01-01 10:10:00
Doe    room1  2018-01-01 10:20:00     2018-01-01 10:30:00
John   room2  2018-01-01 11:00:00     2018-01-01 11:05:00
John   room2  2018-01-01 11:08:00     2018-01-01 11:15:00
John   room1  2018-01-01 12:00:00     2018-01-01 12:08:00
John   room1  2018-01-01 12:10:00     2018-01-01 12:20:00
John   room1  2018-01-01 12:25:00     2018-01-01 12:25:00
John   room3  2018-01-01 12:30:00     2018-01-01 12:35:00
John   room3  2018-01-01 12:40:00     2018-01-01 12:50:00
```

I'm looking at a way to make a query showing the user staying in the various rooms, aggregating the data related to the same room and computing the overall staying time, as follows

```
User  Area    EnterTime               ExitTime              ArregateTime
John  room1   2018-01-01 10:00:00     2018-01-01 10:10:00   00:10:00
John  room2   2018-01-01 11:00:00     2018-01-01 11:05:00   00:15:00
John  room1   2018-01-01 12:00:00     2018-01-01 12:25:00   00:25:00
John  room3   2018-01-01 12:30:00     2018-01-01 12:50:00   00:20:00
Doe   room1   2018-01-01 10:00:00     2018-01-01 10:30:00   00:30:00
```

Looking at various threads I'm quite sure I'd have to use lag and partition by functions but it's not clear how.
Any hints?
Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I think the problem is explained and I don't know how to make the query, if not enough I'm sorry or that

Answer (score 0):

`AggregateTime` isn't really an `aggregate` in your expected result. It seems to be a difference between `max_time` and `min_time` for each `block` where each block is set of contiguous rows with same `(users, area)`.

```
with block as(
    select users, area, entertime, exittime,     
         (row_number() over (order by users, entertime) -
          row_number() over (partition by users, area order by entertime)
         ) as grp
    from your_table
    order by 1,2,3
)
select users, area, entertime, exittime, (exittime - entertime) as duration
from (select users, area, grp, min(entertime) as entertime, max(exittime) as exittime
      from block
      group by users, area, grp
    ) t2
order by 5;
```

I made some changes to '[Resetting Row number according to record data change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680999/resetting-row-number-according-to-record-data-change)' to arrive at the solution.

Comment: Hi, I've created a sqlfiddle with my table creation and your suggested query, 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d8db/2/0
if you have a look to the 'block' part, the grp column doesn't change when badge b passes from area a to area b, perhaps I'm making any mistake. thanks

Comment: grp number does not change but the combination of column `(badge, area, grp)` changes from `(B,A,3)` to `(B, B, 3)` which you care about. Isn't that sufficient for your problem?

Comment: Hi, I wasn't able to test the whole query (removing the comments) because I have an error
ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" Position: 293
Any hints? thank you very much

Comment: @DanGrow working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0d8db/6/0 I realized that the expected output you provided is not consistent. Second row `John,   room2` has exittime that should be `2018-01-01 11:15:00` instead if I understand your question correctly.